# How do you ensure that has_many always "has a minimum"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Let's say I'm writing code to model a bus depot.

Each `fleet` of busses always has at least one `bus`. I want to figure out the best way to enforce this minimal number in the model. The last bus in a fleet can never be destroyed unless the fleet itself is itself being destroyed.

One approach is to capture the relationship on the `bus` object.

```
class Bus
  ...
  before_destroy :check_minimum_busses_on_parent
end
```

However this widely disregards the principle of single-responsibility. The bus is dealing with fleet issues which aren't its issue.

I could instead create a `bus_observer` with a `before_destroy` method. Everything's now single-responsibility again it feels like we've got more objects rattling around than necessary.

```
class BusObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
  def before_destroy bus
    false if bus.fleet.busses.count <= 1
  end
end
```

This will certainly do the job but I'm not 100% happy about the decoupling from the `Fleet` class where it really belongs.

**Still allow for the fleet to destroy its last bus**

In order to allow for the possibility that the parent `fleet` object might itself be destroyed and want to get rid of its last bus it I also end up needing some cross-communication so the bus can figure out whether the fleet's getting the chop too:

```
class BusObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
  def before_destroy bus
    if  bus.fleet.busses.count <= 1 
      false unless bus.fleet.currently_being_destroyed?
    end
  end
end
```

This is obviously entering the realms of pure ugliness. One could wrap it up into a method `.bus_can_be_destroyed?` that sits on the fleet object but that's not a whole lot better.

What is the cleanest way to get what I'm after?

Answer (score 1):

Could you have a Decommissioner class which, given a bus, handles the business logic appropriately? This seems clear and reasonable.

It could even be an ActiveRecord model, if you were interested in logging the decommissioning event.

Something along the lines of:

```
class BusDecommissioner
  def initialize(bus)
    @bus = bus
  end
  def decommissionable?
    @bus.fleet.buses.size > 1
  end
  def decommission!
    @bus.destroy if decommissionable?
  end
end
```

Comment: You could also perhaps define a decommission! method in an Association Extension, so that you can call _fleet.decommission!(bus)_.

Answer (score 1):

Would it work with [Association callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#label-Association+callbacks)? You could use the `before_remove` callback and halt the removal, according to the docs.

Comment: I think this could be exactly what I'm looking for. Will confirm post-experimentation

Comment: Do you have any experience with getting this callback to work? I can't make it fire: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893877/why-isnt-before-remove-firing-in-this-has-many-association/8894085#8894085

Comment: No, I haven't tried it myself. I just found it in the documentation and thought that it could answer your problem. I tried to browse the rails source code on github but I didn't find anything there. So it might have been removed :-(

Comment: Update, I also found this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-callbacks

You might have to accept the record as an argument in the callback method? Don't know if it would work, but the guide and the example says that you should

Comment: Ty. I can't mark your answer as correct because I don't think it's possible but have upvoted both it and your comments to give you the points