# Why isn't "before_remove" firing in this has_many association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to run some code before an object is removed from a `has_many` association.

I thought that I would be able to do this with the `before_remove` callback however for some reason this isn't firing and I don't understand why.

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :limbs, before_remove: :print_message

  def print_message
    puts 'removing a limb'
  end
end

class Limb < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
end
```

While this code should print *"removing a limb"* during the destruction of a limb but it doesn't.

```
p = Person.create;
l = Limb.create person: p;
p.limbs.first.destroy
# SQL (2.1ms)  DELETE FROM "limbs" WHERE "limbs"."id" = ?  [["id", 5]]
# => #<Limb id: 5, person_id: 3, created_at: "2012-01-17 11:28:01", updated_at: "2012-01-17 11:28:01">
```

Why does this `destroy` action not cause the `print_message` method to run?

**EDIT - does this `before_remove` callback exist?**

A number of people have asked whether this callback exists. Although I can find very few further references to it, it is documented in the Rails documentation:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#label-Association+callbacks

It's an association callback though rather than a root ActiveRecord callback

**Edit 2 - why not just use `before_destroy` on Limb?**

Some people are asking why I'm not using the `before_destroy` callback on Limb. The reason is that I want person to check that there is a minimum number of limbs and that the last one is never destroyed. This is the original problem:
[How do you ensure that has_many always "has a minimum"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8882349/how-do-you-ensure-that-has-many-always-has-a-minimum)

Comment: There is no before_remove. At least I don't know it and the doc http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html seems to confirm my opinion.

Comment: @lucapette it's related to `ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods`, not to `ActiveRecord::Callbacks`.

Comment: @shime Good to know. I didn't run into it. There's always something to learn ;)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`before_remove` callback exists as an option in [Associations callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#label-Association+callbacks). It's not the same as `before_destroy`, which is an [ActiveRecord callback](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html).

This is how you use it:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :limbs, :before_remove => :print_message

  def print_message(limb)
    # limb variable references to a Limb instance you're removing
    # ( do some action here )
    # ...
  end
end

class Limb < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
end
```

You're also calling a `remove` method incorrectly.

```
p = Person.create
l = Limb.create(:person => p)
p.limbs.first.destroy
```

Here you're calling it on `Limb` instance, that's why nothing is triggered.
Call it on an association you created:

```
p = Person.create
l = Limb.create(:person => p)
p.limbs.destroy(l)
```

**EDIT**

For preserving minimum of associated objects you can do something like this:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :limbs, :before_remove => :preserve_mimimum

  def preserve_minimum(limb)
    raise "Minimum must be preserved" if limbs.count == 1
  end
end

class Limb < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
end
```

This however does not get triggered on `p.limbs.destroy_all`, so you have to do something like this `p.limbs.each {|l| p.limbs.destroy(l)}`

Why it does not get triggered by `destroy_all`?

Because of this:

```
def destroy_all(conditions = nil)
   find(:all, :conditions => conditions).each { |object| object.destroy }
end
```

It iterates over each element of an association and executes destroy action on an object and not on an association, that's why.

Comment: Hi shime, the purpose of the method is to protect the limb from being destroyed however `destroy` is called so it may be that this method doesn't work for me anyway. That said I can't actually get it to work using your methodology either - are you sure your code does work?

Comment: It works. I've edited my post to support "preservance of minimum".

Comment: Thanks for that. I did get it working and your examples helped show how it wouldn't unfortunately address the issues I need to deal with. That said, I'm unclear as to when this would be useful - even `p.limbs.first.destroy` doesn't trigger the callback

Comment: No problem. I think I know why `destroy_all` does not trigger anything, since it should work by iterating over elements of associaton. I'm sure why `p.limbs.first.destroy` does not work. With that code you're doing an action on the `Limb` instance object, and it's essentialy the same as `limb.destroy`, since both methods doesn't have anything to do with association and therefore association callback.

Comment: +1 Very descriptive answer! This was incredibly helpful! Thank you. :)

Answer (score 2):

Replace`before_remove` with `before_destroy`.

**Edit** - handling minimum number of limbs

```
class Limb < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :creature
  before_destroy :count_limbs

  def count_limbs
    return false if self.creature.limbs.length <= self.creature.min_limbs
  end
end
```

That return false will, I believe, stop it from being destroyed.  Although I could be wrong

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I've updated the question though to show where it does exist and why I need it.

Comment: Whether or not `before_remove` exists, `before_destroy` should fix the issue.  Is there a specific reason you are looking to use something else?  Am reading your link on before_remove now.

Comment: this kind of replacement throws `ArgumentError: Unknown key(s): before_destroy`

Comment: I appreciate your input however this method does not address my problem. I don't want to do the validation on the limb object because it violates the single responsibility principle. This is a validation that belongs with Person, not limb and I want to figure how to achieve that end: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8882349/how-do-you-ensure-that-has-many-always-has-a-minimum

Comment: Maybe this is bringing out my naivety, but doesn't sticking limb validation on Person violate the single responsibility principle?  Shouldn't limbs be responsible for themselves?

Comment: @LeeQuarella, that's a fair question but while each limb is responsible for itself, the number of limbs attached to the person is the person's responsibility. Imagine if there were lots of classes that could each take different numbers of limbs (pig, seahorse, elephant) - you would want the policing of minimum limb-number to be policed by the Animal rather than the limb

Comment: Thoughts on this edit?  Creatures are responsible for knowing their min_limbs, and limbs are responsible for validating themselves against that. (This conversation is probably getting outside the scope of SO comments, but it is fun :D)

Comment: @LeeQuarella - it is interesting and actually having written that it's the job of the creature to validate it I'm beginning to wonder whether it is and whether your approach is in fact the correct one. It is the one I have already used elsewhere but it felt like there was a smell in there. Your edit btw does the job as required - ty

Comment: I've had some discussion with my brother about this, here is the convo: http://pastebin.com/0ncNwSUf

Comment: @LeeQuarella I really appreciate you taking the time on this. Your comments made me rethink my approach and I've ended up going with a hybrid between the two where the `Person` contains the logic determining whether the limb can be destroyed but the limb uses a `before_destroy` callback to call that method and determine whether it's good to go. I think it's got the right combination of responsibilities - it probably makes sense that the limb has the ultimate decision over whether it can go. Love the peg-legged question btw :)

Answer (score 0):

I can't say I've ever used the `before_remove` callback before, and not sure it exists.

The before destroy callback should be on the Limb model rather, and should look like this:

```
class Limb < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
  before_destroy :print_message
  def print_message
    puts 'removing a limb'
  end
end
```

Comment: The before_destroy callback can be used on the limb however that doesn't address the issue I have which is that I want the Person to disallow limbs from being destroyed if there are too few of them. I've updated the question to reference the docs for before_remove